# Create a graph object from an adjacency list of edges

Tags: r, igraph

I'm not sure if this is a trivial or stupid question but I was wondering if it's possible to create an `igraph` object using `R` (or whatever software) and starting from an adjacency matrix of edges. For example, I'd like to recreate the following graph:

[image]

just by specifying the adjacency matrix of the edges using a matrix:

```r
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#> [1,]    0    1    0    0    0
#> [2,]    1    0    1    1    0
#> [3,]    0    1    0    1    0
#> [4,]    0    1    1    0    1
#> [5,]    0    0    0    1    0
```

or a list:

```r
my_list <- list(
  "1" = c(2), 
  "2" = c(1, 3, 4), 
  "3" = c(2, 4), 
  "4" = c(2, 3, 5), 
  "5" = c(4)
)
my_list
#> $`1`
#> [1] 2
#> 
#> $`2`
#> [1] 1 3 4
#> 
#> $`3`
#> [1] 2 4
#> 
#> $`4`
#> [1] 2 3 5
#> 
#> $`5`
#> [1] 4
```

<sup>Created on 2020-03-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

As far as I know the function `igraph::graph_from_adj_list` works only using an adjacency matrix of vertices, i.e.

```r
# packages
library(igraph)

my_list <- list(
  "1" = c(2), 
  "2" = c(1, 3, 4), 
  "3" = c(2, 4), 
  "4" = c(2, 3, 5), 
  "5" = c(4)
)
my_list
#> $`1`
#> [1] 2
#> 
#> $`2`
#> [1] 1 3 4
#> 
#> $`3`
#> [1] 2 4
#> 
#> $`4`
#> [1] 2 3 5
#> 
#> $`5`
#> [1] 4

g <- graph_from_adj_list(my_list)
plot(g)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-03-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

which is not what I want.

Comment: From a quick look I haven't found any out-of-the-box code to do this. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LineGraph.html gives a few refs for *reconstructing the original graph from its line graph* but https://www.cmm.ki.si/~FAMNIT-knjiga/wwwANG/The_Adjancency_Matrix-5.htm suggests it wont be unique

Comment: maybe paper "https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/ILIGRA%3A-An-Efficient-Inverse-Line-Graph-Algorithm-Liu-Trajanovski/ba644f5fe606ad60cfbc96fcd03463be5bbc163b" has some code at https://www.nas.ewi.tudelft.nl/people/Stojan/code/ILIGRA.zip

Comment: @user20650 Thank you very much for your suggestions, in the next days I will check the paper and I will see if it's possible to apply that algorithm to my case.

Comment: @G5W ok,thanks. I'm not an expert on graph theory so I was just wondering if that was a reasonable idea. Regarding your example I would say that the edge 1 cannot be connected at the same node as edges 3 & 4 because the first row of the matrix says that the first edge is connected only with the second one but I'm not sure if that's what you mean.

Comment: @G5W; '*One does not specify an "adjacency matrix of the edges"*' I don't think that is accurate, it was new to me but  I found many examples in the literature; this old paper *determining graph properties from matrix representations: kirkpatrick* & https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_graph